# Return a pandas series from a loop

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops

I have a pandas dataframe `nike` that looks like this:

```
    rise1      run1       position
    1          0.82       1
    3          1.64       2
    5          3.09       3
    7          5.15       4
    8          7.98       5
    15         11.12      6
```

I am trying to make a function that calculates grade (rise/run) and returns it as a pandas series. I want to use X points ahead of the current position minus X points behind the current position to calculate grade (i.e. if X = 2, the grade at position 4 is (15-3)/(11.12-1.64)).

```
def get_grade(dataf, X=n):
    grade = pd.Series(data = None, index = range(dataf.shape[0]))

    for i in range(X, dataf.shape[0] - X):
        rise = dataf.loc[i + X, 'rise1'] - dataf.loc[i - X,'rise1']
        run = dataf.loc[i + X, 'run1'] - dataf.loc[i - X, 'run1']
        if np.isclose(rise, 0) or np.isclose(run, 0):
            grade[i] = 0
        elif rise / run > 1:
            grade[i] = 1
        elif rise / run < -1:
            grade[i] = -1
        else:
            grade[i] = rise / run

    return grade
   
get_grade(nike, X= 2)
```

When I call the function, nothing happens. The code executes but nothing appears. What might I be doing wrong? Apologies if this is unclear, I am very new to coding in general with limited vocab in this area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set a variable equal to the function (so setting the variable equal to your return value) and then print/display that variable. Like `df = get_grade(nike, X= 2)` `print(df)`. Or put a print call in your function

```py
def test_function():
    df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,3,4], "col2":[4,3,2,1]})
    return df
df = test_function()
print(df)
```

Or

```py
def test_print_function():
    df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,3,4], "col2":[4,3,2,1]})
    print(df)
test_print_function()
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are working is suboptimal. In general, a `for` loop + `.loc` in pandas repeatedly is a signal that you're not taking advantage for the framework.

My suggestion is to use a [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) window, and apply your calculations:

```
WINDOW = 2
rolled = df[['rise1', 'run1']].rolling(2*WINDOW + 1, center=True)\
                              .apply(lambda s: s.iloc[0] - s.iloc[-1])
print(rolled['rise1'] / rolled['run1'])
```

---

```
0         NaN
1         NaN
2    0.977654
3    1.265823
4         NaN
5         NaN
dtype: float64
```

Now, as to your specific problem, I cannot reproduce. Copying and pasting your code in a brand new notebook works fine, but apparently it doesn't yield the results you want (i.e. you don't find `(15-3)/(11.12-1.64)` as you intended).