# How to get a variable defined in a function

Tags: python

I am new to python and cant seem to get this right. Please see the code below;

```
import random
words = ["first", "second", "twenty-one"]
word = random.choice(words)
```

So this gives you a random word from the list. Now i want to remove words with '-';

```
import random
def get_random_word():
    words = ["first", "second", "twenty-one"]
    word = random.choice(words)
    while "-" in word:
        word = random.choice(words)
```

Now how do i print the word?

The thing is i have tried return still doesn't work

```
import random
def get_random_word():
    words = ["first", "second", "twenty-one"]
    word = random.choice(words)
    while "-" in word:
        word = random.choice(words)

    return word
print(word)
```

So lets stop this hassle and someone respond to my original code that i am trying to get to work;

```
import random
words = ["one", "two"]

def get_valid_word():
    word = random.choice(words)
    while '-' or ' ' in word:
        word = random.choice(words)

    return word

print(get_valid_word())
```

So apparently removing the "OR" in the while loop fixed the problem but in theory it should work. Idk why but i have been getting errors related to using "OR" in Pycharm before. Thanks to everyone that tried to solve this and if you know why did it not work with the or and worked without it i would be pleased to know.

Comment: You should `return` your result to the caller. (Not just a Python thing -- that's how one gets a result out of a function back to its caller in pretty much all modern programming languages... and also just about all of them that were modern 40 years ago).

Comment: `Return` the result ... then don't forget to set a variable equal to your function to actually use the returned value. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73071055/return-a-pandas-series-from-a-loop/73071178#73071178) for a similar problem

Comment: Just keep going through a Python tutorial. You assign the result of calling the function to a variable: `result = get_random_word()` and then output it using `print(result)`.

Comment: Your or syntax is wrong. It should be “‘-‘ in word or ‘ ‘ in word”.

Comment: Also have you checked to make sure you’re using consistent tab characters, meaning you’re not mixing tabs and spaces for indentation?

Answer (score 1):

You must type

```
print(get_random_word())
```

Comment: This worked in the code that i have put above in the question but i tried it before answering this question in the original code but it didn't work there. The difference was in the file it didn't work the list was out of the function.

Comment: @Sneakoz It shouldn't matter where the list is.

Comment: The answer should say `print(get_random_word())`

Comment: @Sneakoz if you want to print use print function else you can get the variable from the input value to print function

Comment: Have checked to make sure you’re using consistent tab characters, meaning you’re not mixing tabs and spaces for indentation?

Comment: I type with my phone and this is a little hard

Comment: I realized I put my comment in the wrong place, sorry.